# I have arrays describing my data's spatial position and associated value. How do I make this into a meshgrid?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mesh

I have strangely arranged spatial data. It describes something like temperature. There are two arrays of spatial coordinates, `x` and `y`. Here is how those data are arranged:

```
plt.scatter(x,y, c=x.index, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow)
for label, xi, yi in zip([str(s) for s in range(x.size)], x, y):
    plt.annotate(label, xy=(xi, yi))
plt.show()
```

[image: strange arrangement of points]

I also have a vector `u` describing the temperature field. each entry `u[i]` corresponds to positions `x[i]` and `y[i]`. **How can I reshape `u` into a meshgrid, where each mesh position corresponds to the positions described by `x` and `y`?** For example, this could allow me to put the meshgrid of `u` into `plt.contourf` and it would look similar to `plt.scatter(x, y, c=u)`. I don't want to assume that the grid is square.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
nx = len(np.unique(x))
ny = len(np.unique(y))
U = np.reshape(u, (nx, ny))
```

Comment: Are the values of all the `x` in one column exactly the same? If so I'm pretty sure you can simply `lexsort` `x` and `y`. This gives you an index vector which you would then apply to `x`, `y` and `u`.

Comment: `x` is a vector, not a matrix, so I think it only has one column. The values are not all the same.

Comment: I mean the apparent columns in your plot. like `x[[0, 3, 23, 34, etc.]]` would be the leftmost column. Still not all the same?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yes they are exactly the same. How would I use `lexsort`?

Comment: Something like `idx = np.lexsort((x, y))` (maybe you have to swap x and y, not sure). And then `xo = x[idx]` `yo = y[idx]` `uo = u[idx]`.

Comment: are the labels in your plot the indices of of `u`

Comment: @f5r5e5d No. I posted the code I used the generate the plot. The labels are the order the x and y points are stored in.